# pandas is not converting type string to float

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've tried replacing the ',' with blank field.

```
df['amount'].replace(',','', regex=True).astype(float)
```

Error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 

df['amount'] = df['amount'].astype('float64')
```

I still get the same error. The sample data looks like:
**5,000.00** and **1,00,000.234** values.

How can I convert it to float?

Btw, I'm reading a json file! with only the path of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need assign back:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'amount':['5,000.00', '1,00,000.234']})

df['amount'] = df['amount'].replace(',','', regex=True).astype('float64')
print (df)
       amount
0    5000.000
1  100000.234
```

If does not work check if some bad values:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'amount':['5,000.00', '1,00,000.234', 'a']})
print (df)
         amount
0      5,000.00
1  1,00,000.234
2             a

print (df.loc[pd.to_numeric(df['amount'].replace(',','', regex=True), errors='coerce').isnull(), 'amount'])
2    a
Name: amount, dtype: object
```

Then is possible convert bad values to `NaN`s:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'amount':['5,000.00', '1,00,000.234', 'a']})
print (df)
         amount
0      5,000.00
1  1,00,000.234
2             a

df['amount'] = pd.to_numeric(df['amount'].replace(',','', regex=True), errors='coerce', downcast='float')
print (df)

       amount
0    5000.000
1  100000.234
2         NaN
```

---

If use `pd.read_csv` for `DataFrame` add parameter `thousands=','`:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file, thousands=',')
```

Comment: I'm using json and the 1st answer does not work but the second answer does but it does not convert the datatype to float.

Comment: Give me a sec. I explain more.

Comment: @jason - I think second paragraph is for check problematic values, then I add solution for repalce them to `NaN`s. Please check it.

Comment: I checked it out but it did not convert the datatype to float but downcast='float' works!

Comment: @jason - If use only `downcast='float'` it working nice? Not necessary `errors=coerce` ?

Comment: @jason - But I cannot see your data, so hard to know.

Comment: The answer which jpp has provided below works and so does your answer this :  **pd.to_numeric(df['deposit_amount'].replace(',','', regex=True), errors='coerce', downcast='float')**

Comment: Should I use this answer ? THis is correct right ??

Comment: @jason - sure, I want to say I am afraid `downcast='float'` is not enough, already need `errors='coerce'`

Comment: So should remove downcast?

Comment: @jason - Try it without it, if working nice, I think you an remove it with no problem.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for the heads Up!! :) You are too fast and too good !!! Thanks again!

Comment: @jason - Glad can help!

Answer (score 1):

Using `pandas.to_numeric` with `pd.Series.str.replace` works for this:

```
s = pd.Series(['5,000.00', '1,00,000.234'])

s = pd.to_numeric(s.str.replace(',', ''), downcast='float')

print(s)

# 0      5000.000
# 1    100000.234
# dtype: float64
```

However, a better idea is to fix this at source, if possible. For example, `pandas.read_csv` has arguments which allow you to account for such numeric formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Our values like 5,000.00 would be converted to 5000.00 as a float:

```py
df['Withdrawal Amt.'] = [float(str(i).replace(",", "")) for i in df['Withdrawal Amt.']]
```